# How to look for anagrams in 1 or 2 dictionaries?

Tags: comparison, anagram

This is our code now:

**#anagram** is a word formed by rearranging the letters of a different word

```
text = open("words.txt")
counter = 0
d = {}
e = {}

for word in text:
w = word
a = list(word)
s = sorted(a)
counter += 1
d[counter] = s
e[counter] = s
print(d)
print(e)
```

We want to ask python to show us the words which have the same values/letters. So for example: AAB is the same as BAA.

Our file exists from:

```
aba
aab
acaba
ackba
abaca
casaba
```

Does anyone know how to program this?

Comment: Can you please edit your code to fix the indentation please ? FYI: For your question you should consider comparing ordered strings, if ordered words are equals it means that the words are anagrams

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to improve the quality of your question by: use correct formatting (Python is a white-space sensitive language); provide some example input/output of what you want to achieve; explain what are you expecting from your current code; point out what are you struggling with. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).